# Confluence space and Page Analytics

Tags: web-services, google-analytics, analytics, wiki, confluence

I'm currently working on Confluence with BPM.
I am new to Confluence as a developer and user as well.

My questions are:

- How to see total space visit in a day, a week, a month and a year? (exact count not any chart)
- How to get statistics of top 5 pages visited in a day, week, month and year?
- How to get statistics of users who use the space or wiki frequently?

**Note** : *This statistics should ignore all the counts of user "ABC".*

Comment: Which version of Confluence? 3.5, 4 or 5? Which platform? Windows or Linux? Cloud or Server? From a user or an Admin perspective? Does the answer need to be Confluence only or can third party plugins / services be used such as [Piwik](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/de.smartics.piwik.atlassian.confluence.smartics-piwik/server/overview) or [Google Analytics](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.go2group.plugins.confluence-ga/server/overview)? Can you access the Confluence index files? Are you willing to [pay](https://www.appfusions.com/display/CONFENGAGE/Home) for a plugin?